# How can I get a div to appear when a textarea is in focus? (both are children of the same form element)

Tags: html, css, forms, css-selectors

I'm having trouble getting my CSS to work :(

HTML

```
<form action="/api/submit/" method="post">
    <textarea name="post" rows="2"></textarea>
    <input type="url" name="url" />
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="someName" value="someValue" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

CSS

```
form > input {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; top: -2.5em; left: 0;
}
form > textarea:focus + input {
    display: block;
}
form > div {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: -6.66%;
}
form > textarea:focus + input + div {
    display: block;
}
```

What I want is to have the `div` and the `input` elements to appear when the `textarea` is in focus. At the moment, only the `input` element is doing what its supposed to do.

Also, I *can* select the `div` if I don't use `:focus` on the `textarea`, which is strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your problem is the positioning. However, it's worth noting that unless you are using the most current browsers, this combination of CSS rules is not going to work reliably in older browsers - IE < 8 particularly.

Furthermore, the other inputs will disappear as soon as you blur the textarea. Is this your goal? That doesn't seem like a very usable form...

Although I commend using CSS whenever possible, I would suggest looking into handling your behavior with JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not particularly worried about browser compatibility. This is a tech preview site so you need a current browser for anything to work, anyway.

Comment: Oops, I didn't think about that.. JS it is then!

Answer (score 3):

with css3 you could use

```
form > textarea:focus ~ div {
    display: block;
}
```

where ~ is a general previous sibling selector [w3c css3 selector recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)

demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaf0/bDvgK/)